# Trying to pass data from a database into a bootstrap modal when opened. How do I go about doing this?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to pass data from my database into a modal form. The purpose of this modal is so users can edit their data within the database and then save the changes to said data.

I've tried many tutorials on YouTube, as well as reading previous responses on this site using methods such as doing it through Ajax and Bootstrap Modal Event Listener & Ajax and jQuery Click function but due to my inexperience with these programming languages I've yet to understand as the examples are vastly different to my project. Below is my code for form as well as the tables in my database

Button used to open the modal:

```
 <a class="badge badge-success p-2" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editPostModal">Edit</a>
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editPostModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Update Post</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <form action="editdata.inc.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> // PHP File I would like to use to run a possible "update" query
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="themeContent" class="form-control" placeholder = "Enter theme"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="visualIdeaContent" class="form-control" placeholder = "Enter idea"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="captionContent" class="form-control" value="<?= $captionContent; ?>" placeholder = "Insert caption"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="date" name="dateContent" class="form-control" placeholder = "Select date"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="linkContent" class="form-control" placeholder = "Insert URL"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="file" name="visualContent" class="custom-file" placeholder = "Upload picture"/>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" name="editdata" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Database

```
Name: annexcms
Table: content

uidContent // Unique ID
themeContent
visualIdeaContent
captionContent
dateContent
linkContent
visualContent
```

All in all, I expect the modal to:

1) Open and display data from the database tied to a specific User ID

2) Have the ability to save any changes made to that data when clicking the "Save Changes" button.

3) Have the saved data updated in the database.

This is the last part of my CRUD application as I've mastered the other three features. Appreciate any help I can receive.

Comment: Ajax is what you will need so show us what you tried in that regard that didn't work or where you got stuck trying it

Comment: One thing I would suggest is create a very simple form page, without modal, and practice submitting that simple form with ajax. Once you get that working try it in a modal. One method that will help a lot is using [`jQuery.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: @charlietfl one of the methods I tried brought data back to the form but in a disorganized fashion. I would share the code, but unfortunately, it has been deemed too long for the comment section. Is there another medium of some sort that I can use to show you this?

Comment: By editing the question

Comment: @charlietfl  I'm new to this website, excuse my stupidity. I'll figure it out

Comment: No worries...there is an edit link right under the question

Comment: @charlietfl so after trying to give it another go, figured it out myself :) I'll share what worked for me

Comment: Hey...good news! Next stop how to do the validation!

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 controller methods:

```
public function respondData($id)
{
    //you can ever check if id exist here or if exist at all and 
    //throw any exeptions if not exist, this is just example
    if($checkUser->exist($id))
    {
        $userData = array('id' => '1, 'name' => 'Name');
        return json_encode($data);
    }
    throw new \Exeption('User does not exist');
}

public function saveData()
{
    if($_POST)
    {
       if(($checkUser->exist($_POST['id'])))
       {
          //get value from POST and check and update
           return true; // or message and parse it if it was ajax request
       }
    }
    throw new \Exeption('Method not allowed');
}
```

JQUERY:
You need to get data from your user and bind it to modal
You can do this this way:
add `data-user` to you button or a link and other method to trigger modal opening:

```
$(document).on('click', '#your-link', function () { 
        var data = $(this).data('user');
        $.post({
            url: 'url_to_first_action' + '?id=' + data,
            data: data,
            success: function(data){
                //here you parse JSON ARRAY to your fields
            },
        });
    });
```

Now after user submit you data to second action you can do this with straight POST request or use the ajax to serialize() post.

Answer (score 0):

So after tinkering with previous code, I got this to work.

My table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Theme</th>
          <th>Visual Idea</th>
          <th>Caption</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Visual</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
        $table  = mysqli_query($conn ,'SELECT * FROM content');
        while($row  = mysqli_fetch_array($table)){ ?>
          <tr id="<?php echo $row['uidContent']; ?>">
            <td width="200" data-target="themeContent"><?php echo $row['themeContent']; ?></td>
            <td width="300" data-target="visualIdeaContent"><?php echo $row['visualIdeaContent']; ?></td>
            <td width="600" data-target="captionContent"><?php echo $row['captionContent']; ?></td>
            <td width="100" data-target="dateContent"><?php echo $row['dateContent']; ?></td>
            <td width="200" data-target="visualContent"><img id="imgsrc" src="<?php echo $row['visualContent']; ?>"width="200"/></td>
            <td style = "display:none" width="100" data-target="linkContent"><?php echo $row['linkContent']; ?></td>
            <td width="170">
              <a class="badge badge-primary p-2" role="button" href="<?php echo $row['linkContent']; ?>" target="_blank">Link</a>
              <a class="badge badge-success p-2" href="#" data-role="update" data-id="<?php echo $row['uidContent'] ;?>">Edit</a>
              <a class="badge badge-danger p-2" role="button" href="action.inc.php?delete=<?php echo $row['uidContent'] ;?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this post? This process cannot be undone.');">Delete</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        <?php }
        ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

The script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
  //  Gets values in input fields
  $(document).on('click','a[data-role=update]',function(){
    var id  = $(this).data('id');
    var themeContent = $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=themeContent]').text();
    var visualIdeaContent = $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=visualIdeaContent]').text();
    var captionContent = $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=captionContent]').text();
    var linkContent = $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=linkContent]').text();
    var dateContent = $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=dateContent]').text();
    var visualContent = $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=visualContent]').text();

    $('#themeContent').val(themeContent);
    $('#visualIdeaContent').val(visualIdeaContent);
    $('#captionContent').val(captionContent);
    $('#dateContent').val(dateContent);
    $('#linkContent').val(linkContent);
    $('#visualContent').val(visualContent);
    $('#uidContent').val(id);
    $('#updatePostModal').modal('toggle');
  });
});
</script>
```

The only issue is that I'm not getting the image path to display as a thumbnail in the form, but I'll figure it out on my own through research. 
My code is ugly, but at this point, I'm more concerned about the functionality. Thanks everyone.

Comment: fill free to rate my answer if it helps you figure out. :)